# Are psuedo-topologically disconnected "spaces" themselves sets that can be unionized?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

[image]

As you can see, $B_1$, $B_2$, $B_3$ are all disconnected and non-overlapping. Let's say they are sets. Can we take the union of $B_1$ to $B_3$ and create a new set called B?

I don't know how to describe these other than things that are fake pseudo topologically disconnected spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know what a "fake pseudo topologically disconnected space" is, but it doesn't matter. Any pair of sets can be unioned together to form a new set, in any circumstance, no matter what. Whether they are disconnected, overlapping, whatever, they can *always* be unioned together. To "union" two sets just means to form a set consisting of the things that are in each - for example, the union of $\{1, 2, 3\}$ and $\{1, 4, 5\}$ is $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$. Topological properties have absolutely no effect whatsoever.

Whether or not $B$ is also a "fake pseudo topologically disconnected space" is less clear - sometimes the union of two sets with a certain property doesn't also have that property. And since I don't know what such a space is (I know "topologically disconnected" and "pseudo-topological space", but not "fake") I can't confirm whether or not this property is preserved under unions.

Comment: So if I have {1,2,3} from numbers on a y-axis and {1,4,8} from numbers on the x-axis, even though these numbers reside orthogonally because the y and x-axis are orthogonal, we can still take the union of {1,2,3} and {1,4,8}?

Comment: @Cozing Numbers do not exist on axes. *Points* exist on axes. "1 on the y-axis" is the point $(0,1)$. So the first set you mention is the set $\{(0,1), (0,2), (0,3)\}$; the second is $\{(1,0),(4,0),(8,0)\}$. Their union is $\{(0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (1,0), (4,0), (8,0)\}$. One thing you need to realize here: when you write a set, you are writing *all* distinguishing information about it. The set $\{1,2,3\}$ really means "the set consisting of the numbers $1$, $2$, and $3$"; it doesn't get to say where they came from, only what they are.